# Omit database collection when importing from MongoDB to ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm trying to omit a collection from being included when importing from a MongoDB database to ElasticSearch.

https://github.com/appbaseio/abc is being used with a transform file, which has the following code:

```
t.Source('source', source, '/.*/')
.Transform(omit(user_database_bugtest.users))
.Save('sink', sink, '/.*/');
```

Database: user_database_bugtest

Collection to be omitted: users

I assume this is what's not formatted correctly, unless I have to make other changes: user_database_bugtest.users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this transform file code:

```
t.Source("source", source, '/^testcollection$/').Save("sink", sink, "/.*/")
```